# i want to get the form inputs as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
 <form id="notification_form" >
        <div style="display: flex;" id="xx">


        <div style="float: left; width: 40%;margin-left: 1%;">

      <label style="margin-top: -2px">message text on area entrance</label>
        <input style="margin-top: -11px" type="text" id="notf_msg_entrance">

            <label style="margin-top: -11px">message text on area exit</label>
        <input style="margin-top: -11px" type="text" id="notf_msg_exit">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 40%;margin-left: 10%;margin-top: 12px;" >
<!--        <div><input type="checkbox" name="push" value="1"  id="notf_push"> <label>push </label></div>-->
            <div id="right_div">
                <select class='form-control inputstl' id="select_aud"></select>
            <label style="margin-left: 7px;">sms notification</label>
        <input type="tel" id="notf_tel_num" class='form-control inputstl'>
            <label style="margin-left: 7px;">mail notification</label>
        <input type="mail" id="notf_mail" class='form-control inputstl'>
            <div>
              <input style="margin-left: 2px" type="checkbox" class="emergency" value="1" > 
              <label style="float: right;margin-top: -1px;margin-right: 25px;">emergency notification</label></div>
        </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </form>
```

when i make `console.log($('#notification_form').serialize());` it doesn't give me response while it gives me on another form

Comment: Use `name` attributes on your inputs to enable serialization :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All form elements require a `name` attribute in order to be included in the final submitted form data. If they don't include this, the browser will ignore them when preparing the form data to be sent to the server.

The same rule applies to jQuery's `serialize()` method, since it tries to apply the same logic that the browser would use if you submitted the form without using JavaScript.

e.g. your first input box could be changed to something like this:

```
<input style="margin-top: -11px" type="text" id="notf_msg_entrance" name="msg_entrance">
```

Set the name to be whatever name you would like it to appear as when transmitted to the server. Apply this to all the form elements in your form (inputs (including textboxes, checkboxes, radios), selects, textareas etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs need a name attribute.

```
<input style="margin-top: -11px" type="text" name="notf_msg_entrance" id="notf_msg_entrance">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_serialize

Comment: Please, please, please never cite W3 Schools, which is well-known to include incomplete, out-dated or flat out wrong information. If we could purge this abomination of a web site from the face of the earth, whole legions of new web developers would be so much more better off. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) is the place to go.

Comment: Also, link only answers (which is what you've posted) are generally frowned upon and should really just be a comment. I know you can't post comments until you get a rep of 40, but posting poor answers won't get you there. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I actually went and edited my answer to include a sample of an input including the name attribute however that edit doesn't seem to be showing up.

Comment: There is no reason that an edit wouldn't show up. You must not have saved it. Try again.

Comment: If you included HTML but didn't [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then it won't show in the answer - the site will treat it as potential tag injection and suppress it.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: No problem. I'd bookmark that link if I were you. Comes in very handy until you start to memorise the shortcuts!